# How to process parameter sent through $resource get?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-services

In the controller:

```
MyService.get({queryParameter:'MyQueryParameter'}).$promise.then(function(result){
  return result; 
};
```

In the service I have:

```
$resource('/api/path',{
  queryParameter: (function process(queryParameter) {
    //process queryParameter
    return processed_query_parameter;
  })('@queryParameter'),
});
```

In an attempt to simulate what it's normally done:

```
queryParameter: '@queryParameter'
```

However this doesn't seem to work. Nor this:

```
$resource('/api/path',{
   queryParameter: (function process(queryParameter) {
     //process queryParameter
     return processed_query_parameter;
   })(@queryParameter),
});
```

Or this:

```
$resource('/api/path',{
   queryParameter: (function process(queryParameter) {
     //process queryParameter
     return processed_query_parameter;
   })(queryParameter),
});
```

So, how do I access the passed parameter, and process it before I assign it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
angular.module('app').service('MyService', ['$resource', function MyService($resource) {
var rs = $resource('http://localhost:8080/api');

    rs.getPersonalized(params){
        var customParams = {
            queryParameter: params.id
        }
        return rs.get(customParams);
    }

    return rs;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

please see docs.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

try it:

```
MyService.get({queryParameter:'MyQueryParameter'}).then(function(result){
  return result; 
};

$resource('/api/path');
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not help me.